# Get file headers in custom file

Tags: plugin-development, theme-development, headers, get-plugin-data, wp-get-theme

in my one of my plugins i have modules (kind of like plugins in a plugin), is there a function like `get_plugin_data()` or `wp_get_theme()` that will allow me to get the header section of a custom file (by passing the path as a parameter)?

By heading section i mean

```
/*
    Plugin Name: Name Of The Plugin
    Plugin URI: http://URI_Of_Page_Describing_Plugin_and_Updates
    Description: A brief description of the Plugin.
    Version: The Plugin's Version Number, e.g.: 1.0
    Author: Name Of The Plugin Author
    Author URI: http://URI_Of_The_Plugin_Author
    License: A "Slug" license name e.g. GPL2
*/
```

Thanks to @toscho the correct solution was

```
$default_headers = array(
    'Module Name' => 'Module Name',
    'Test Header' => 'Test Header',
    );

$file_data = get_file_data(dirname(__file__).'/some-file.php', $default_headers);

print_r($file_data);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`get_file_data( $file, $headers )`](http://queryposts.com/function/get_file_data/):

```
$file_data = get_file_data( __FILE__, array ( 'Plugin Name' ) );

echo "the name is " . $file_data[0];
```

Make sure the first parameter points to an existing file.

It will find all lines that are formatted like regular plugins headers or the headers of a `style.css`.

In my plugin *T5 Opera Speed Dial Preview* I use it to [show the link to my bug tracker](https://github.com/thefuxia/T5-Opera-Speed-Dial-Preview/blob/master/plugin.php#L212):

```
$data = get_file_data( __FILE__, array ( 'Feedback URI' ) );
return empty ( $data ) ? '' : $data[0];
```

Comment: please see my own answer as i couldn’t figure out how to put code in a comment xXx

Comment: @SofiaRose See my update. You cannot read a directory, it must be a real file.

Comment: so i cant read a file in another directory?

Comment: Of course it can. But the path must be correct. Try [`file_exists()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php) to verify it is correct.

Comment: sorry i was having a stupid moment, i needed dirname(__file__).'/some-file.php' not dirname('some-file.php')

Comment: @SofiaRose Glad you figured it out. :) You should write constants always in uppercase, even a [magic constant](http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php); that’s a useful convention. So `__FILE__`, no `__file__`.